# Regex not being applied correctly

Tags: jquery, regex

I've got an array of string values that is passed through a regular expression check, but there are strings that pass that shouldn't.
I checked the expression on an online regular expression tool (Regexpal.com as an example) and it seems to work correctly, but not when applied.

The expression that I have is as follows:

```
/^\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)|([-])*/i
```

So this should match one or more groups of text reading 
    "(texthere123)" or zero or more of text reading "-"

I'm including a JsFiddle link to indicate this.

```js
var options = ["something", "new", "-", "(testing)"];
jQuery.each(options, function(i, val){
    console.log({i: i, val: val});
    if (/^\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)|([-])*/i.test(i))
        console.log({type: "matched"});
    else
        console.log({type: "not matched"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tnhmy68a/

Comment: Your `i` argument that you're testing is the index (numeric), not the value. Also `|([-])*` matches the empty string, so any input will match

Comment: The current pattern looks somewhat suspicious: do you mean you want to match the entire string matching `\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)` or 1+ hyphens? `if (/^(?:\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)|-+)$/i.test(val))`

Comment: CertainPerformance, an error on my side. I intended to indicate val. Wiktor, yes that is exactly what I tried to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test for `val` instead of `i`, because `i` is the index number. The second part of the regex to match zero or more `-` can be `-*`.

Also you need to force the entire string to match by adding a ^ and $ around each part (note their scope ends at the | separator which is why I included them twice).

```js
var options = ["something", "", "-", "--", "-bla", "not-this", "(testing)", "(texthere123)"];

jQuery.each(options, function(i, val) {
    if (/^\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\)$|^-*$/i.test(val))
        console.log(`Matched     : i = ${i}, val = "${val}"`);
    else
        console.log(`Not matched : i = ${i}, val = "${val}"`);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```